# There is no IFF_RUNNING flag in ifreq structure

Tags: c, linux, networking, ip

I executed a simple test:

`ifdown eth1
 ifup eth1`

then I tried to fetch eth1 interface flags in the following way:

```
                 struct ifreq flags_s;
                 int result = 0;
                 int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);

                 (void)strcpy(flags_s.ifr_name, "eth1");
                 flags_s.ifr_flags = 0;

                 result = ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &flags_s);
                 if (-1 == result)
                 {
                    perror("ioctl");
                    close(sockfd);
                 }

                 if (flags_s.ifr_flags & IFF_UP)
                 {
                    fprintf(stderr, "IFF_UPP+\n");
                 }

                 if (flags_s.ifr_flags & IFF_RUNNING)
                 {
                    fprintf(stderr, "IFF_RUNNING+\n");
                 }
```

In all cases I see only IFF_UP flag and no IFF_RUNNING. Could someone explain why flags_s.ifr_flags does not contain IFF_RUNNING flag?
This is my `netstat -i` output, we can see that flag RUNNING was set for eth1:

`Kernel Interface table
Iface   MTU Met    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
eth0     1500   0 45387749      0 19798101      0  2572141      0      0      0 BMRU
eth1     1500   0      111      0 10484579      0       26      0      0      0 BMRU`

The same is in `ifconfig` output: `UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST`

I have a legacy code with interface supervising functionality using netlink, rtnetlink. When interface brings up, the program checks for IFF_UP and IFF_RUNNING flags. This functionality does not work properly because of the the problem described above.